# Firefox Sprite Sheet Image Not Showing Up

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, sprite

I'm having an issue getting this CSS for a sprite sheet to work on Google Chrome.

```css
image.emo {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
}

image#smile {
  background: url(img/diceSprite.png) 0 0;
}

image#bigsmile {
  background: url(img/diceSprite.png) -19px 0;
}
```

```html
<img class="emo" id = "smile" src="img/blank.gif" 
  width="1" height="1" alt=":)" title=":)" />
<img class="emo" id = "bigsmile" src="img/blank.gif" 
  width="1" height="1" alt=":D" title=":D" />
```

Comment: @ttony21 : Hi, I am using Firefox 3.0.x, cannot see either a smiley image or a black.gif in page source. Not even the alternate text defined by your alt attributes. Am I missing the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
image.emo {
  width:19px;
  height:19px;
}
```

to

```
img.emo {
  width:19px;
  height:19px;
}
```

and the others follow a similar pattern. The element selector is img, not image

Comment: So if that did the trick, you could consider giving me the check mark.  And it's a mistake all of us have made at one time or another, I'm sure. :)

Comment: It's usually the little things that matter the most. Forgetting that it's img instead of image happens to all of us from time to time. Good catch Robusto.

Comment: Really, I blame W3C for calling that tag "img" in the first place. I can't tell you how many times I've had that "duh" moment when realizing I made the same mistake you did. In my mind, "img" is pronounced "image"!